# How do you clear the read-only flag on a file in .NET?

Tags: .net, bit-manipulation, flags

How do you clear the *read-only* flag on a file in .NET *and leave the rest intact*?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Is it a problem with the file in your file system or just the .NET framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo("yourfile.txt");
f.IsReadOnly = false;
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Alconja - Thanks.  I missed that in the Intellisense dropdown and went the flags route instead.  This is definitely easier though.

Answer (score 2):

I would get the FileInfo instance for the file, and then set the IsReadOnly property to false (as per the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly.aspx):

```
new FileInfo("path").IsReadOnly = false;
```

If you insist on using the static GetAttributes and SetAttributes methods on the File class, you can simply do this:

```
File.SetAttributes("path", 
    File.GetAttributes("path") & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

The general pattern when you want to clear a flag on a bitmap is to take the value for the flag (in this case, FileAttributes.ReadOnly), invert it (using the ~ operator) and then apply the inverted value to the value that contains the various flags (in this case, File.GetAttributes("path")).

Comment: @casperOne - Thanks.  I ended up going the bitwise route simply because I wasn't aware of the "IsReadOnly" flag.

Comment: @roygbiv Not a problem.  Glad it helped (and possibly answered your question?)